Is there such generative model that drawing idealized version of dataset?
Suppose there are dataset of handwritten digit of zero. We know that human handwritten are not perfects. But here the model will tries to draw the ideal version of the digit, e.g. perfect circle.
Because I accidentally trained GAN where all random latent vectors input is almost identical to the idealized version of dataset. But for number 7 instead of 0.

Turns out if we feed the generator part without discriminator with real samples and random latent, we got idealized version of the dataset.

